# Symfony 2: How and where to store runtime settings file

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 2 WebApp that uses the `PayPal Rest API` to create and accept PayPal payments.

To be able to redirect each user to a PayPal page in his language, one has to create an [Experience Profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-experience-overview/) for each language/locale.

Each `Experience Profile` has to be created only once. For example once a profile for `US` locale has been create, this profile can be re-used for every customer using the same locale:

1. Customer enters his address and contry XY on my page
2. My page checks if profile for `XY` locale exists
3. Create new profile for `XY` locale and store it OR re-use existing one

Each profile has a unique ID. **Thus I am looking for a method to store Locale/ID pairs**. A simple solution would be a JSON file. **But where to store this file within the Symfony structure?**

Profiles are created on the fly when ever a user from a new country places a payment. Thus this data is created during runtime and because of this it does not belong into the standard `config` dirs of Symfony I think. I do not even know if these folders should accessible/writeable by my code.

**So: What is the right place to store such a file.**

**EDIT:** 
As @JimL pointed out in the comments it would of course be possible to store the data in the DB. However the Payment Bundle I am working on, should be used in different projects and thus be as separated from the rest of the project as possible.

The goal here is, to store the data in **a file, not in the DB**. Of course the DB is much more efficient but in this special case a simple file will be sufficient.

The question is: Where to store this file? First idea is to use `/MyBundle/Resources/config` since this dir holds all other config files. But is this the right place for files that **change at run time** as well?

Comment: Sounds like you could just add it as an entity with a relation to user. Which will then be stored in db

Comment: No, that is not the way to go. The Profile is NOT linked to a specific user. All user that select "USA" as country will use the US-profile. If the same user selects "Canada" on his next purchase, he should use the CA-profile, etc. Additionally the Payment logic is implemented in a separat bundle, so it can be re-used in other project. I would like to keep this data away from the DB.

Comment: Bundles could add db entites as well, I still think this should be in the db. If not linked to the user then linked to the payment

Comment: Of course the DB would be an option but I do not think, that is would be best solution in this case. This is config data that is created at runtime. No Entiy, etc. So the question is: Where to store this kind of config file. I have edited the question to it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Standard Symfony directory structure for 3.x is:

**app/**
The application configuration, templates and translations.

**bin/**
Executable files (e.g. bin/console).

**src/**
The project's PHP code.

**tests/**
Automatic tests (e.g. Unit tests).
Standard Directory Structure is:

**var/**
Generated files (cache, logs, etc.).

**vendor/**
The third-party dependencies.

**web/**
The web root directory.

**You can put it in the standard var directory under your custom directory. Remember about permissions.**

More general info on var directory:
http://www.linfo.org/var.html

Comment: I am using Symfony 2.8 which does not have the `var/` dir. Instead cache, logs, etc. are located in `app/`. I now injected the `kernel.cache_dir` in my PaymentServices and store the data there.

Comment: It's controversial. Clearing the cache will clear your data profiles. Maybe better option is grab the storage location from user configuration.